# Example where $\int_{\text{Int} S} f$ exists and $\int_S f$ does not.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Let $S$ be bounded in $\mathbb{R}^n$, let $f:S\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be bounded continuous function. Give an example where $\int_{\mathrm{Int} S} f$ exists and $\int_S f$ does not.

Notice this is not the same as given $\int_\bar{S} f$ exists and $\int_S f$ not.

I think the key is the following theorem:

Let S be bounded on $\mathbb R^n$, $f:S\to \mathbb R$ be bounded continuous. Let $E$ be the set of points $x_0$ of $\partial S$ (the boundary of $S$) for which $$\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) \ne 0$$ fails to hold. Then $f$ is integrable over S if $E$ has measure zero.

Comment: Are you using Riemann integrability, or Lebesgue integrability?

Comment: @DanielSchepler I assumed he used Lebesgue integrability, having he talked about measure of sets: the theorem he states could not hold in a Riemaniann context (think of $E$ as the Cantor set, for example: the riemann integral of $1$ on $E$ would not be defined)

Comment: Actually I want to ask Riemann integrability

Comment: The I think it would be helpful for everyone to understand your question to clearly state it. What is your definition of a set of measure 0?

Comment: For any given $\epsilon > 0$, you can find a rectangle cover $\{R_i\}$ of the set such that $\sum_i^\infty v(R_i) < \epsilon$

Comment: And how do you define the Riemann integral on a bounded set that is not a rectangle?

Comment: Given a bounded set $S$, then find a rectangle $R$ such that $S$ is a subset of $R$. Then one define $\int_S f = \int_R f \chi_{\!S}$, where $\chi$ is the identity function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let V be the [Vitali set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set). It is bounded, and $\mu\left(\text{Int} V\right)=0$, so a constant function on $V$ trivially satisfies your requirements.